# linear programming : Absolute value in constraint in mathematical model

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

I have a model have an constraint with evaluation of absolute value , a example can be:

function objective :
   $\max \sum(x_i)$
statement:
   $x_i\geq  |(y_i-t_i)|$  for all $i$

but value absolute not is permitted in solver complex , the model is non-convex

Comment: Constraint: $ x_i\geq \sqrt {(y_i-t_i)^2} $ .. Abs is not ok,It is a trick for convexity although am not sure..

Comment: yes that's a problem, it is solved by tree exploring algorithm (branch and cut for example), I don't know why matlab doesn't offer a function to solve this kind of linear programming with absolute values problems. netherless, some  matlab toolboxes should have that function.

Answer (score 2):

Write the inequality with the absolute value in two seperate inequalities. First define

$y_i-t_i=a_i$

$t_i-y_i=b_i$

Then $x_i$ have to be larger or equal to $a_i$ and $b_i$:

$x_i\geq a_i$

$x_i \geq b_i$

$\texttt{numerical example:}$

*Case 1:* Suppose $y_i=3$ and $t_i=2$. $a_i$ becomes 1 and $b_i$ becomes -1. Therefore $x_i$ has to be greater or equal than 1.

*Case 2:* Suppose $y_i=2$ and $t_i=3$. $a_i$ becomes -1 and $b_i$ becomes 1. Therefore $x_i$ has to be greater or equal than 1.

In both cases $x_i$ has to be greater or equal than 1.